# Single search criterion multiple results

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I need to output the results from a column of sorted data with only a single search criterion. There are sometimes multiple occurrences for the same criterion. LOOKUP finds the first occurrence only. I need to input in a cell cell to match is in J8:J581 and the corresponding data to be displayed isN8:N581

```
J   K L M N
bob       RED
bob       BLUE
Bob       Green
Sue       yellow
Sue       white
fred      grey
pete      brown
```

.

```
input=bob
output=    bob  RED
                BLUE
                Green
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking to return rows like your sample above, use an Excel Table.

1. Select your data
2. Create a Table `Insert>Tables>Table` (check My Table has Headers box)
3. Once the Table has been created, simply choose your filter button (down arrow in Table Header row) and choose your filter value (e.g. in your sample, choose Bob), this will return only the "Bob" rows.

Here's a before image:

[image: Table]

And, after:

[image]

**EDIT:**  Based on your additional info, I would consider adding a Pivot Table based on your Data Table. This will allow you to create an "outlined" view of your info, to better see which campsites have only one ID vs. multiple ID's. It would look something like this:

[image]

Also, to @pnuts note, Excel is limited to 10,000 items in a drop down (i.e. filter) list, but there is no documented limit to table members. I've had tables with 10,000s rows.

**EDIT2:** If you want to easily find only repeated values, a Pivot Table is absolutely the way to go.

1. Take your initial data table and add a "counter" row.  `=IF([@Name]=D1,F1+1,1)` This will return a count of how many rows have the same Name.
2. Create a Pivot Table `Insert>Tables>Pivot Table` from your data.
3. Format your Pivot Table like this:

   - Row Labels = `Name`, `Code`, `Counter`, and turn off sub-totals and grand totals for all values.
   - Filter Counter = Clear 1, this will show only Names with multiple values.
   - Filter Name = any specific campsite name you're interested in.

[image: Filtered Pivot]

Comment: I apologise for not explaining properly; what i did was to only give a very simplified example. What I have is a list some 2000 large.; of campsite and their campsit number. some campsite have the same name but different ID numbers. I want to search by name and produce all ID numbers for that name

Comment: I would like to type in a cell and excel searc and return results instead of trawling through a list to find names. I don't think filter shows which are duplicate entries until results are displayed

Comment: Instead of adding comments clarifying your question, please edit the question with the additional info, that will help everyone keep track of the additional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your input cell is A1, and your output cells are A3 for the name and B3:B.. for the output range (with the end of the B range going down as far as the maximum number of results you expect to see).

For A3, put the formula `=A1`.

For B3, put the formula

```
  =IFERROR(INDEX($N$1:$N$99,SMALL(IF($J$1:$J$99=$A$3,ROW($N$1:$N$99)-ROW($N$1)+1),ROWS($N$1:$N1))),"")
```

This is an array formula and needs to be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination. You can then copy it down to the bottom of your output range.

Note that the formula is hard-coded for an input list with a maximum of 99 rows. You can change this to whatever length you need. While it would be possible to reference the entire column (J:J and N:N), there would be a performance hit that you probably want to avoid.

#### How the formula works

Working from the inside out, the formula first compares the name on which the lookup is to be performed (cell A3) with the full list of names (up to 99 names in the range J1:J99). That comparison is shown in line 6 of the function breakout shown below.

The product of that comparison is an array with True values for a match and False values for a non-match, e.g., {False, False, False, False, True, True, False, ... etc.}.

Then, a comparison is made between that array with an array that can be thought of as the "line numbers" of the list of names: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... 99}. This comparison is done by the IF statement in lines 6-8 of the formula chart.

The comparison is element-by-element. If an element of the name comparison array equals True, then the IF returns its corresponding line number; if the element equals False, the IF returns FALSE. Using the two example arrays above, the result of the IF statement would be {False, False, False, False, 4, 5, False, ...}.

[image: elements of the match function]

Continuing on, the SMALL function (starting on line 8 of the function outline) is used to get the kth smallest element of this new array from the IF. The "k" in this case is supplied by the expression ROWS($N$1:$N1), which will simply count up from 1 to 99 when the whole formula is copied down from row 1 through row 99 (ROWS($N$1:$N1) = 1, ROWS($N$1:$N2) = 2, and so on).

So, SMALL will first find the smallest element of the array produced by the IF, *ignoring* the elements that are False. In other words, it will return the first line number where the name being compared matches a name in the lookup list of names. In our example, that is the number 4, as shown in the 6th column of the table below.

The wrap-up step uses INDEX on the lookup values to fetch the element corresponding to the line number that has been calculated. In this case, the 4th item in the color list example for the question is "yellow". (The IFERROR makes sure that a blank is shown when the formula fails to find a match.)

That was the result produced by the first copy of the full formula. When it is copied down to the next cell, the only thing that changes in the calculation is the value of "k" for the SMALL function, which advances to 2. And the second smallest line number that was found is 5, which yield the value "white".

[image]